# Execute script when host is shutting down

Tags: linux, bash

I have a Linux script which I require to get executed just before the host is going down.

Where do I need to place the file in order to work?

Comment: It depends on your init; systemd/sysvinit/runit/upstart...

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu/CentOS:

Keep your script in */etc/init.d/* and create a symbolic link in */etc/rc0.d* started by K50 (K for kill, 50 for execution priority)

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/your_script.sh /etc/rc0.d/K01your_script
```